# How to adjust fontsize for Weight and biases?

Tags: wandb

I need to make bigger font size of Weight and biases.

Because font size looks so small as below.

[image]

I have found way to make bigger font but I can't get any solution.

But I could see some photos as below looks not bad.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Will there be any solution?

One more problem is when I adjust width and height of plot,

most left label is cut. So label can't be seen fully as below.

"ball_tree" is cut so there is only "ll_tree"

[image]